# WebAPI Authentication

Tags: c#, entity-framework, authentication, asp.net-web-api

Do you see any security issues with this authentication approach or have any suggestions?

WebAPI is REST-based.  The user logs in by calling the Authentication Controller and expects a 401 if unauthenticated or a 200 with a session token in the header.

[GitHub](https://github.com/jeremyspatrick/AngularWebApiEFExample)

```
Session session = null;
try
{
    session = Models.User.Login(user);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var errResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        Content = new StringContent("Invalid Username or Password"),
        ReasonPhrase = ex.InnerException.ToString()
    };
    throw new HttpResponseException(errResponse);
}
```

On every call except Authentication the request is intercepted and expects a session header.  If a session exists in the database then the request is authenticated.

```
protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        //Unauthorized
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers[SessionHeader] == null)
        {
            var errResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(SessionError),
                ReasonPhrase = SessionError
            };
            return errResponse;

        }

        string sessionHeader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers[SessionHeader];


        Session session = Session.Lookup(sessionHeader);

        if (session == null)
        {
            throw new SecurityException("No session record exists");
        }
        else if (session.Expired)
        {
            throw new SecurityException("Session Expired");
        }
        else
        {
            session.LastAccess = DateTime.Now;
            session.Save();
            var identity = new SecurityPrincipal(session);
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = identity;
            HttpContext.Current.User = identity;

        }
```

The session lookup is done with Entity Framework

```
public static Session Lookup(string sessionId) {
    using (var context = new SingleAppContextCustom())
    {
        var session = (from s in context.Sessions.IncludeChildren()
                        where s.SessionId == sessionId
                        select s).FirstOrDefault();

        return session;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you looking for general improvements of this code? or if this is the way you should authenticate users? Not quite clear what you expect for answers.

Comment: Mostly if there's any security issues but general code review as well

Comment: You shouldn't use a Session, you should really use something along these lines.  http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/looking-at-how-asp-net-mvc-authorize-interacts-with-asp-net-forms-authorization  That way you can use the Authorization Attributes.

Comment: Its not using a server side Session.  That's just the name of the variable.  Its using a token passed in the header.  the session is looked up in the database.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you want to give as little information as possible for why access was denied.  So I would change that section of code to:

```
if (session == null || session.Expired)
{
    throw new SecurityException("Access Denied");
}
```

Presumably this exception gets converted to an appropriate HTTP status code.

`SendAsyc` is an odd name for a function that enforces security, but maybe you have a reason for that.  That said, it seems like there's something missing since I don't see where it is async or returns a `Task`.